# Remove mapping drives from RDP to user from exteral network

Tags: security, vpn, firewall, group-policy, terminal-server

I would like to know if you guys have a solution to my problem.
I have a terminal server 2012 that can be accessed remotely after a VPN connection and from the LAN.

My question is how can I create a policy that denies drive mapping when a specific user connects via VPN, and to allow drive mapping when connecting via LAN for the same user.

What do you think will be the best approach for that matter?

thanks,

Comment: As far as I know, you can't really do this with group policy. Perhaps blocking SMB traffic over the VPN would do what you need?

Comment: Clarify: Do you mean block VPN users from mapping drives in their session on the term server, or block VPN users from mapping drives from their physical system to the term server?

Comment: Yes, block only VPN users from mapping drives, and to allow mapping within the LAN only. User accounts are the same for both VPN connection and from the LAN controlled by AD.